# How can I set up git over lan and without internet on mac for iOS Developing?

Tags: xcode, git, repository, local, offline

We are 3 iOS Developers in company. We want to use git for pushing and pulling code in local. But due to internet restriction, I can't get verfication by  github email and password. So how can I setup and make git repository offline on 1 mac and accessed from other macs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)or [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) to host the repository locally.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have some shared directory between your three machines and use that as your "url" (i.e., `git clone /my/shared/directory/myproject` or whatever). Then you do not need any server component running anywhere, at all.

A better way would be having a local ssh server, then it's `git clone user@host:/path/to/repositories/myproject`.

In both cases, you would need to create that remote first by whatever means (`git init --bare`, or cloning it from some existing version of your repository), depending on what you already have.

The `git` documentation explains all this in detail (including pros and cons), it's both straight forward and standard.

Or, of course, any kind of local GitLab or whatever you want to install, if you are able to host something like that locally.